# Add volley to my project in Android Studio

Tags: android, import

I am trying to use volley in a project but I don't know how to do it. 
I have downloaded it from git, after that, import project, and select Gradle (I don't really know what to choose),  the new dialog, I have to choose a Gradle home, but I don't know...

Is not possible add a dependence from the file "build.gradle" inside the project?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!
The only solution I found was open the project with Eclipse and export it to .jar file.
After that, I added the .jar to my project, I placed in my libs folder. 
At the end, I added to my "build.grandle" the next dependence.

dependencies {

```
compile files('libs/volley.jar')
```

}

That's all.